# Proof about Gaussian integers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Show that if $\lambda \in Z[i]$ and $Norm(\lambda)=p$ where p is a prime number then $\lambda$ is prime in $Z[i]$

Approach: not so much to say

$\lambda=a+bi$ where a and b are integers, so $N\lambda=a^2+b^2=p$. From there, maybe we should start analyzing what a and b could be. One of them has to be odd for sure except when p=2. If p=2 then $\lambda=1-i$ or $\lambda=1+i$ and we know that they are primes.

Comment: Details depend on your definition of prime. You may be using "irreducible." In that case, use the fact that $N(uv)=N(u)N(v)$.  If you are using the more standard definition of prime, the argument is similar.

Comment: the Gaussian integers is a principal ideal domain  : the fundamental theorem of arithmetic works there, so prime is the same as not divisible by anything else the units and itself (times the units)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\text{Norm}(\lambda) = p$. If $\sigma \cdot \tau = \lambda$ for some $\sigma, \, \tau \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$, then by the multiplicativity of the norm, we have $\text{Norm}(\sigma) \cdot \text{Norm}(\tau) = p$. It follows that one of $\text{Norm}(\sigma), \, \text{Norm}(\tau)$ is equal to $p$ and the other equals $1$. Suppose WLOG that $\text{Norm}(\sigma) = 1$. Then, at last, we see that $\sigma$ must be a unit, so $\lambda$ is prime.

Comment: Correct, $\lambda$ is prime because we see that one of it's factors is always a unit, so therefore the other factor must be and associate and by definition a Gaussian integer which has no other divisors than its associates and the units is said to be prime. Correct?

Comment: @daniel by definition of a principal ideal domain

Comment: @daniel Yes, that's right. $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ has the happy fortune of being a Euclidean domain.

Comment: what is that xd /?

Comment: @daniel A Euclidean domain? It is an integral domain ($a \cdot b = 0 \Rightarrow a = 0 \text{ or } b = 0$) that satisfies the Euclidean algorithm (division with remainder).